# Python remove specific zeros from string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv which I am loading into a pandas dataframe.

I want to change a specific column to lose leading zeros from the month and date, and seperates the hour into another column.

For example, I have a column, called *DateTime* comes in like "03/17 04:00:00" or "01/01 15:00:00"  and I would like to change the column (and also I guess to concatenate 2010 to the end of the date) to a "Date" Column with "3/17/2010" and a "Time" Column with "4:00:00" or like the second example, a "Date" column with "1/1/2010" and a "time" column with "15:00:00".

I'm pretty sure I would like to do this with regex_replace, I think that would be easiest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this assumes your data is all formatted the same:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ["03/17 04:00:00", "01/01 15:00:00"]})

dates = []
times = []

for x in df.DateTime:
    d, t = x.split()
    d = re.sub("^0", "", d)
    d += "/2010"
    dates.append(d)
    times.append(t)

df['Date'] = dates
df['Time'] = times
```

Comment: Loops in pandas are obviously slow and better is avoid it.

Comment: Your answer demonstrates that well. I'm still learning pandas, so I broke it down into a loop. Hopefully the skill range of the answers will help people.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df[['Date', 'Time']] = df.DateTime.str.split(expand=True)
df.Date = df.Date.str.lstrip('0') + '/2010'
print (df)
         DateTime       Date      Time
0  03/17 04:00:00  3/17/2010  04:00:00
1  01/01 15:00:00  1/01/2010  15:00:00
```

Similar solution with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) by regex `^0` (first `0` in string):

```
df[['Date', 'Time']] = df.DateTime.str.split(expand=True)
df.Date = df.Date.str.replace('^0', '') + '/2010'
```

**Timings**:

```
In [10]: %timeit (jez(df2))
1 loop, best of 3: 483 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit (jez(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 500 ms per loop

In [12]: %timeit (user39(df1))
1 loop, best of 3: 740 ms per loop
```

**Code for timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ["03/17 04:00:00", "01/01 15:00:00"]})
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
#[200000 rows x 3 columns]
print (df)
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

def jez(df):
    df[['Date', 'Time']] = df.DateTime.str.split(expand=True)
    df.Date = df.Date.str.lstrip('0') + '/2010'
    return (df)

def jez1(df):
    df[['Date', 'Time']] = df.DateTime.str.split(expand=True)
    df.Date = df.Date.str.replace('^0', '') + '/2010'
    return (df)    

def user39(df):
    dates = []
    times = []

    for x in df.DateTime:
        d, t = x.split()
        d = re.sub("^0", "", d)
        d += "/2010"
        dates.append(d)
        times.append(t)

    df['Date'] = dates
    df['Time'] = times
    return df

print (jez(df))
print (jez(df2))
print (user39(df1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module has what you need with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). You should save regex as a last resort, as it's less readable and more prone to error.

> *classmethod* datetime.**strptime**(*date_string*, *format*)
>
> Return a `datetime` corresponding to *date_string*, parsed according to *format*. This is equivalent to `datetime(*(time.strptime(date_string, format)[0:6]))`. `ValueError` is raised if the *date_string* and *format* can’t be parsed by `time.strptime()` or if it returns a value which isn’t a time tuple. For a complete list of formatting directives, see [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

The documentation contains the directives, but here is an example you could implement in your code:

```
import datetime


def convert_time(tm):
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(tm, "%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
    dt.year = 2010

    parsed_date = "{month}/{day}/{year}".format(*dt)
    parsed_time = "{hour}:{minute}:{second}".format(*dt)

    return parsed_date, parsed_time
```